# html table with width:100% ignores margin-right:200px

Tags: html, css

I want a table thats inside a div to take up all the width of the div, except of 200 pixels at the right side. To do this i tried to set the margin-right to 200px and make the table take up all space with width:100%.

http://timgame.de/test/ddnet/skins/index.php

As you can see the table takes up 100% of the div and there is no space of 200px at the right. My browser is iceweasel(debian version of firefox).

Do you know any way to achieve what i described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `padding-right` on `.block` instead of `margin-right` on the `table`